# Reference request: Category Theory for Theoretical Physics

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, soft-question, physics

I have seen that there are already reference requests questions for category theory. I would like to ask for resources and textbooks that are more oriented towards theoretical physicsists. I'm looking for an introduction to the subject, but would greatly appreciate material that demonstrates the possible use of category theory and its applications in theoretical physics.

Answer (score 1):

I would maybe recommend reading this paper, IF, you already have some background information in algebra, or topology, and things like that. [https://math.berkeley.edu/~erabin/The%20Categorical%20Language%20of%20Physics.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eerabin/The%20Categorical%20Language%20of%20Physics.pdf)

There is also a book;https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-53763-5_52.

There is also a post on mathoverflow;https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34861/how-is-category-theory-actually-useful-in-actual-physics

And a whole wikipedia page; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_quantum_mechanics